# setting the select items in form,after fetching them from DB

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, widget

first of all excuse me for my lameness in django, python and html.

I added  widget to html, and I want to fill the items from the database. I tried the following but its not working, it shows only the obvious ('ALL' item):

HTML:

```
<select name=\"accountName\" >
    <option value=\"ALL\">ALL</option>
    {% for item in select_items %}
    <option value=\"'+item.accountName+'\">'+item.accountName+'</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Python:

```
class StartPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    select_items = db.GqlQuery( "SELECT * FROM Registration" )
    self.response.out.write(template.render("tst.html", {'select_items': select_items}))
```

Note, the DB do contains stuff,and not empty.
Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a django expert, but I think your templatehas some errors.

```
<option value=\"'+item.accountName+'\">'+item.accountName+'</option>
```

should be

```
<option value="{{ item.accountName }}">{{ item.accountName  }}</option>
```

For more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Answer (score 3):

Your django syntax is wrong. It should be like this:

```
{% for item in select_items %}
<option value="{{item.accountName}}">{{item.accountName}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

And you should not be escaping double-quotes either, e.g.

```
<select name=\"accountName\" >
```

Should simply be

```
<select name="accountName" >
```

Also, your python code has indentation problems, but I suppose that has to do with the way you pasted it here, and not an actual problem in your code.

Comment: Isn't a whitespace significant between the {{ and }} ?

Comment: @JonClements no, not in current versions of django, ie. the versions that are supported by GAE.

Answer (score 2):

I don't imagine you want to be escaping the HTML.

```
<select name="accountName" >
    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
    {% for item in select_items %}
    <option value="{{ item.accountName }}">{{ item.accountName }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The rest at a glance looks okay, but my GAE is rusty.

Hopefully you'll get a better answer.